# How to pass input field component to Amplify UI Authenticator

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify

I'd like to pass custom input fields to my authenticator component. All I can apparently do is to pass header or footer components, but no components for the body.

I'd like to pass my own input field component to use the Material UI input fields.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: If you'd like to add an attribute please first consider using the Sign Up Attributes prop. In some instances you may want to add an app-specific attribute. In those cases you can add a new form element to the Sign Up form fields. Be aware the HTML name attribute on the new form field must match the name of the Cognito attribute. If the cognito attribute is a custom attribute it must have the custom: prefix in the HTML attribute name.

See the doc: https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/react/connected-components/authenticator/customization#sign-up-fields